# Canvas drawtext gives blurry image

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am new to Android development. I know there must be a easy solution, but I'm unable to figure it out.

I am drawing an image using `canvas.drawText(number, margin, 50, mPaintText)`. Here is how I've initialised TextPaint. `mPaintText = new TextPaint()` and `mPaintText.setTextSize(4f)`. The number I am trying to draw is `1234567890`.

When I see the image from gallery. It looks very tiny, which is perfect for me. But, after zooming too, it's not clear. It seems to be losing resolution. I don't want to increase font size though, because the space it occupies relative to image size is absolutely perfect to me. Any insight ? [Actual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nasiX.jpg)  [Zoomed in Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppr4m.png)

Comment: Could you clarify your problem? Is your problem with the screenshot itself? Or is it with the size of the text on the device?

Comment: @stan0 no, it's not screen shot problem. I agree size is small i.e. 4f. My idea is by zooming in one should be able to see it clearly, if it doesn't lose resolution. Oh, yes, while saving, i used CompressFormat.JPEG, called getDrawingCache().compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File(Path)));